Query N rows around the row id with complex ordering in Django ORM
According to the reference id, I want to query N rows, so that the row with the reference id would be in the middle. I know how to do it when the QuerySet is simply ordered by id column, but my solution falls apart when I want to order the results by a column other than id (as ids are not sequential anymore) or by multiple columns (e.g. (title, created_at)).
For example, if I had 5 items in the table below, and wanted to query 3 items with a reference id of 3, it would select rows with id 2, 3 and 4:



Id
Title




1
One


2 (Selected)
Two


3 (Selected)
Three


4 (Selected)
Four


5
Five



I tried using Window() function with RowNumber() expression to assign row numbers to a sorted list of items, and then query items before and after the reference id row number, which, unsurprisingly, did not work as row numbers are recomputed on each query.

Visual example:


So you have a primary key of an object (3 is suppose), and some ordering criteria (title and created_at`), and you want to N rows before and N rows after that record? (just to know if I understood it correctly)?

@willeM_VanOnsem Yes, just the number of rows are different as I want to query N rows in total. For example, if N is an odd number, that would be floor(N / 2) rows before, include the reference record, and floor(N / 2) rows after.

Can you please show what you have "... tried using Window() function with RowNumber() ...", and what is wrong about the output? Why does it not work when row numbers are recomputed? Are you changing the table in between?
